# Need to get position of an UIImage animating from top to bottom of screen

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am using animation for an UIImageView. So,that an image is animating from top to bottom of  iPhone screen. I gave start and end positions for that imageView for animation. While it is   moving, I  want to know the current position of that image on the View.

Can any ne help in this regard.
Thank You

Answer (score 1):

You can get position...

```
-(SLfloat) getYPos
{
    SLfloat pos = 0;
    CALayer *layer = yourAnimationView.layer.presentationLayer;
    if(layer)
        pos = layer.frame.origin.y;

    return pos;
}
```